# C++ Builder 2009 - Is There a Way to Determine Unreachable Forms?

Tags: c++, refactoring

I'm using C++ Builder 2009.

I got put on an old project which has been developed over the course of many years with many developers. I've noticed that some of the forms in the project aren't really implemented and might of been used for POC work at some point. I'm hoping to clean up the project, which will be followed by me refactoring some of the repeatative code in the project.

Based on this, my question is, is there a easy way to determine which forms cannot be reached from an initial form? E.g. I have an entry point form and all forms used in the program should have a path form that form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are doing runtime type lookup based on class names, it's pretty easy to solve this problem. If you think a class is unused, delete it. If all your code compiles and links, then it wasn't used. If you get unresolved references, then it was used.

Comment: Simple and brilliant solution. Thx!